# Automatically Load All Webpage Data/Automatically Scroll to End

Tags: javascript, web, instagram

Take https://www.instagram.com/instagram as an example. If you click on 'Followers', a list of all the followers is loaded, but only a few are loaded at a time, and you need to continually scroll until all data is loaded.

Is there a way in Javascript to automatically load all the data, or maybe even automate the scrolling for that particular div?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A few things to consider.

The method Instagram is using to show some followers until you scroll to get more is called [Infinite scrolling](http://scrollmagic.io/examples/advanced/infinite_scrolling.html).

Basically, all we have to know is that this method is implemented on the client, that is, in the browser, using JavaScript.

The first solution is: if you can reverse engineer the Instagram code (minified I suppose) and find the good methods to call, you can force fetch new items even if you didn't scroll.

On the other hand, another technique would be to constantly simulate a scroll to the end, I let you refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6761659/simulate-scroll-event-using-javascript) on how to.